# CSS equivalent to Photoshop's Justify-All

Tags: css, photoshop, justify, text-align

I'd like to take an h2 element and span it's text across the width of it's div.

```
text-align:justify;
```

only spreads the text if it's width is greater than the width of it's container... kind of like Photoshop's justify-left

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CSS:

```
h2 {text-align: justify;}
h2 span {width: 100%; display: inline-block;}
```

HTML:

```
<h2>This is a h2 heading<span></span></h2>
```

Note that this adds a unvisible extra line, resulting in too much height. You might want to compensate for that:

```
h2 {text-align: justify; height: 1.15em;}
```

And for a very neat markup, only working for browsers other then IE7 or below, you could use the `::after` selector:

```
h2::after {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

See [demo fiddle of all three solutions](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/DbwxJ/10/).

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out *why* this works, actually :-)

Comment: @Joey The 100% width span ensures two lines of text, resulting in the justification of the first line. It requires `inline` for being addable to the text, and it requires `block` for accepting the with; hence the `inline-block`.

Comment: @All note that the 100% applies to the parent's width.

Comment: Aaah, that makes sense. Indeed. Somehow I only got so far as thinking that the span then would fill the remaining space. My bad. But maybe the span should be reduced in height a bit :-)

Comment: @Joey That's a very good point. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. See edit.

Answer (score 5):

Time machine answer for when the [CSS 3 Text Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align-last0) becomes a recommendation:

```
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: justify;
```

It won't be of much use before then, though.